# Change the div content from click in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can i make this work with AngularJS? Have this list left-side, and need to change the center div content from the click in this list.

I'm using NG-CLICK and NG-REPEAT to get the click and generate the list from a JSON.

```js
angular.module('duall')
.controller('documentationController', [
 '$scope', 
 '$http', 
  function($scope, $http){

 $scope.docs = [];
 
 $http.get('static/titles.json').success(function(doc){
  $scope.docs = doc;
 }).error(function(error){
  console.log(error);
 });



 $scope.cliked = function(index){
  $scope.item = $scope.docs[index]
 };

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="documentationController">
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col s3" >
    
    
    <div class="input-field col s12" >      
      <input id="search" type="search" ng-model="q" aria-label="filter docs"/>
      <label for="search"><strong>Pesquise Algo! :)</strong></label>
      <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
    </div>
    
    
      <ul class="animate-container">
        <!-- <li ng-repeat="docs in docs | orderBy:'title' | filter:q as results "> -->
        <li  ng-repeat="docs in docs | filter:q as results ">
          <i class="material-icons tiny">search</i>
          <a ng-click="cliked($index)" href="">{{docs.title}}</a>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <br>
        </li>

        <li ng-if="results.length === 0">
          <strong>Nada encontrado :(</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>  
    
        
  </div> <!-- Fim col s3 -->


  <div class="col s9">
  <div class="container">
      CONTENT CLICKED MUST BE HERE!
  </div>
  </div>

  </div><!-- Fim col s9 -->


</div><!-- fim ROW -->
</div><!-- Fim Controller -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the ng-click you can call a function that affect a variable that will contain what you want to see in your container. the following code is only a sample to show you the idea :

First in a ng-repeat you can call a function with ng-click directive :

```
 <li  ng-repeat="docs in docs | filter:q as results ">
      <i class="material-icons tiny">search</i>
      <a ng-click="cliked($index)" href="">{{docs.title}}</a>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <br>
    </li>
```

Function that will affect a specific variable

```
$scope.cliked = function(index){
    $scope.item = $scope.docs[index]
};
```

Variable that you can display in the good container :

```
  <div class="container">
      {{$scope.item}}
  </div>
```